# How to join two different array and display order by date in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I have two array named as payment and invoice. i need to display these arrays order by Invoice date and Payment Date ASC.

Controller Code :

```
$reqsales=Sales::Where('inv_date','>=',$request->input('frmdate_submit'))->Where('inv_date','<=',$request->input('todate_submit'))->Where('customer_id',$request->input('clients'))->get();


$reqpayments=Paymenttransaction::Where('transaction_date','>=',$request->input('frmdate_submit'))->Where('transaction_date','<=',$request->input('todate_submit'))->Where('transaction_category',1)->Where('transaction_type',2)->Where('transaction_cus_vendor',$request->input('clients'))->get();
```

View code is below

```
@foreach($reqsales as $sales)
<tr>
<td>{{date("d M Y",strtotime($sales->inv_date))}}</td>
<td>Invoice - {{$sales->inv_prefix.''.$sales->inv_no}}</td>
<td align="right"> {{number_format($sales->invoice_totalamt,2)}} @php $debitamt+=$sales->invoice_totalamt; @endphp</td>
<td></td>
 </tr>
@endforeach

@foreach($reqpayments as $payments)
<tr>
<td>{{date("d M Y",strtotime($payments->transaction_date))}}</td>
<td>Payment for {{$payments->sales->inv_prefix.''.$payments->sales->inv_no}}</td>
<td></td>
<td align="right">{{number_format($payments->transaction_amt,2)}} @php $creditamt+=$payments->transaction_amt; @endphp</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Currently Displayed

[image]

Need to Display

[image]

Comment: where are your controller code, need to use left join

Comment: @Akbor Controller Code Updated

Answer (score 1):

You can't order by if you have two different arrays. In your current scenario, all your invoices gets printed before printing payment.

So, you have to handle this in a single Query, in the sense.
You need to get all the data (both Invoice & Payment) in a single Query Builde like so,

```
$data = SomeCommonTable::leftJoin('invoice...')
                        ->leftJoin('payment...')
                        ->selectRaw(...)
                        ->orderBy('date','asc/desc)
                        ->get();
```

If you can't achieve like the above query, you need to `unionAll` with `selectRaw` same in both the `queryBuilder`, once you union it, you will be able to add `orderBy('date','asc/desc')` in your union query. You can refer to [docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions) for more details on `union`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from query then you have to simply use the `union all` where you can select the inv_date and transaction_date column in same row.

There is another way to do this in the php. You can use array method.

Use This:

```
$reqSalesPayments = array_merge($reqsales, $reqpayments);
$inv_date = array_column($reqsales, 'inv_date');
$transaction_date = array_column($reqpayments, 'transaction_date');

$arr = array_merge($inv_date, $transaction_date);
array_multisort($arr, SORT_ASC, $reqSalesPayments);

foreach($reqSalesPayments as $sales){
    //Print the table
}
```